# How to get PHP pass utf-8 string to JavaScript through jQuery $.load() utility function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, utf-8

I have some problem to get the utf-8 string from PHP using jQuery $.load() utility function.

File 1: myrecord.txt, saved in utf-8 encoding using Notepad++

```
<p>你好， jQuery Ajax with load method.</p>.
```

File 2: myrecord.php, saved in utf-8 encoding using Notepad++

```
<?php
  echo '<p>你好， jQuery Ajax with load method.</p>';
?>
```

File 3: loadTest.html, saved in utf-8 encoding using Notepad++

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Load Example</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <script type="text/javascript"           
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').load('myrecord.txt');
    });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
      <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I run loadTest.html as is, the result I got is correctly displayed as

你好， jQuery Ajax with load method.

However if I change the load method in file 3 to $('div').load('myrecord.php'), then the display changes to

???jQuery Ajax with load method.

What's wrong? Please help.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Can you check out the headers that the PHP script is outputting?

Comment: What is the encoding of the page?

Comment: Amadan,All the files are in utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Pekka, How do I check the headers that the PHP is outputting?

Comment: I wasn't refering to the files, but to what the browser thinks the encoding is; the two can differ considerably. For the main page, View -> Encoding. For both the main page and the AJAX request, use the network panel of the developer tools for your browser (can't say in more detail without knowing which browser you're using) and looking for Response Headers, then finding the line beginning with `Content-Type`. If present, it typically says something like `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try loading that file using php file by using readfile function and that function should have header for utf-8 output?

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
readfile('myrecord.txt');
```

In addition see if following URL can be of additional help: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8

Comment: Yeah, sending an explicit header is the only thing I can think of, too

Comment: Dharmavir, Thanks a lot. It worked using your code. Pekka, if I only add the explicit header in front of my previous code in file 3, it still does not work. Maybe the readfile() is the magic.

Comment: You should check what headers your server sends out by default for php scripts: `curl --head http://yourhost/path/to/myrecord.php|grep 'Content-type'`